# REST Web Service not working

Tags: spring, web-services, rest

I am just trying to create a simple test web service.  I want to access the User in XML format at the following url: http://localhost:8080/Online_Shopping/dispatcher/rest/hello, but when I go to the URL nothing is displayed.

Here is my code for the service:

```
package com.shopping.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.shopping.model.User;
@Path("/rest")
public class RESTController {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public User getUser() {
        return new User("paymon","123",true);
    }

}
```

The following code is in my spring-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.shopping.controller" />
```

This is in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dispatcher/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: where does "Online_Shopping/dispatcher" come from in your url?

Comment: dispatcher servlet

Comment: Why are you using JAX RS annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Your application is running on port 8080 , so to access this URL you need to add in your servlet dispatcher the "Online_Shopping"

```
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>Online_Shopping/dispatcher/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

or Just access your api without Online_Shoppping

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Spring MVC's annotations instead and use @Controller or @RestController to annotate you controller to be registered as a spring controller.

Try this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
public class RESTController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces = "application/xml")
    public User getUser() {
        return new User("paymon","123",true);
    }

}
```